# System.Threading.Timers или System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо инициализировать порядка 1000 таймеров. Каждый таймер должен обрабатывать свой метод, метод в аргументе принимает грубо говоря ID. Каждый таймер живет, столько тиков, сколько определяет метод. Но тут еще загвоздка в том что этот метод - тик, должен определять к какому таймеру он принадлежит и на время выполнения тела метода застопориться.

допустим метод :

```
public void TimerTick(GUID id)
{
//тут кое какой код
if(TaskHasNextStep(id))
дать таймеру делей и опять зайти в данный метод
else
иначе убивать таймер
}
```

Comment: зачем 1000 таймеров?

Comment: Расскажите, какую именно задачу вы решаете. Может быть, для неё можно обойтись другими средствами?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу @VladD, что вы хотите сделать? Больше десятка таймеров бывает нужно крайне редко, даже для полноценного планировщика задач достаточного одного таймера.

Comment: @VladD У меня есть некий конвеер. Данный конвеер манипулирует более 300 таймерами, должен. То есть он запускает все их в один момент, и следит за их состояниями. Пишу нагрузочное тестирование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы передать в обработчик ID, нужно воспользоваться либо user state (который есть у `System.Threading.Timer`), либо просто упаковать его в лямбду (работает всегда).

Пример:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run();

    void Run()
    {
        using (var t1 = new System.Timers.Timer(200) { AutoReset = false })
        {
            // id = 0 упаковываем в лямбду
            t1.Elapsed += (o, e) => Tick(0);
            t1.Start();

            using (var t2 = new System.Threading.Timer(
                        // id = 1 упаковываем в лямбду, аргумент userstate игнорируем
                        userstate => Tick(1), null, 400, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite))

            using (var t3 = new System.Threading.Timer(
                        // id = 2 передаём как userstate, лямбдой не пользуемся
                        Tick2, 2, 600, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite))

            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    // понадобится каст к int, т. к. TimerCallback принимает object для универсальности
    void Tick2(object id) => Tick((int)id);

    void Tick(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Timer {id} elapsed");
        // остальной обработчик
    }
}
```

(не забудьте в вашей программе вызвать у таймеров, которые вам больше не нужны, `Dispose`!)

Вывод программы:

```
Timer 0 elapsed
Timer 1 elapsed
Timer 2 elapsed
```

Таким образом, с точки зрения передачи состояния (id) нет разницы, каким таймером пользоваться, лямбды вытянут всё.

С точки зрения перезапуска таймера: для перезапуска у `System.Timers.Timer` можно установить `t1.Enabled = true;`, а у `System.Threading.Timer` — `t2.Change(400, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);`. Таки образом, снова-таки оба таймера эквивалентны.

Из отличий:

- у `System.Threading.Timer` callback единственный, устанавливается в конструкторе, и не может быть отменён, а у `System.Timers.Timer` есть событие `Elapsed`, на которое можно подписываться и отписываться в любой момент;
- `System.Threading.Timer` выполняет callback всегда на пуле потоков, а событие `Elapsed` у `System.Timers.Timer` можно привести в UI-поток у WinForms, используя [`SynchronizingObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx). С WPF сложнее, т. к. [`Dispatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) не имплементирует [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx), и приходится [писать адаптер](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ab5042d-ce72-4b3f-96c6-315660dcb4b2/isynchronizeinvoke-in-wpf?forum=wpf) или [вставлять кусочек WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765241/276994).
- `System.Timers.Timer` доступен только под .NET Framework, но не под .NET Core или UWP.

Пользуйтесь тем, интерфейс которого вам больше по душе.

Comment: Я бы предостерёг об опасности создания таймеров в виде локальных переменных: сборщик мусора может их собрать и они перестанут работать. @ParanoidPanda

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Если обернуть их в блок `using`, то по идее не соберёт. Но вы правы, я поправлю код.