# Включение программы через время

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе варианта времени из `CheckedListBox` и подтверждении кликом по `Button`, программа выключилась после прохождения выбранного времени? Так же должен быть пункт 'Выключить' чтобы отключить таймер.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вызвать колбек при нажатии на кнопку? Запустить таймер? По выбору другого пункта остановить таймер? В вызываемом по таймеру коде завершить приложение?

Comment: Думаю скорее все эти пункты. Кроме 'Вызвать колбек при нажатии на кнопку'.

Comment: Тогда, возможно, имеет смысл разбить вопрос на более мелкие вопросы.

Comment: Запуск и остановка таймера есть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/652951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понимаю, вам нужно что то вроде :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (checkedListBox1.Text.Count() > 0) 
        {
            string check = checkedListBox1.Text.ToString();
            switch (check) 
            {
                case "1 час": timer1.Interval = 360000;
                    break;
                case "30 сек": timer1.Interval = 30000;
                    break;
                case "45 сек": timer1.Interval = 45000;
                    break;
            }
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();    
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что если нужна на 1 час? Как прописать это не в миллисекундах?

Comment: Можно вместо `int check` использовать `string check` и далее `switch case` для установки интервала таймера.